# How to pass arguments to existing vscode commands

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I would like to be able to run an existing vscode command or extension and pass arguments to it.  From my research so far this is what I would expect the vscode task.json to look like, but it does not work.  What am I doing wrong?

```
    {
        "label": "open index html in editor",
        "command": "${command:workbench.action.files.openFile}",
        "args": ["/home/host_user/src/index.html"]
    },
    {
        "label": "liveView index html",
        "command": "${command:extension.liveServer.goOnline}",
        "args": ["/home/host_user/src/index.html"]
    },
```

If I run the file command it opens a vscode prompt to select a file.  If I try to liveView the file, it runs live view on my root workspace (as no path is getting passed to it).

This is the extension I'm trying to open with file with:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer

Thanks

Comment: to open a file use [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links#open-a-file), to use VSC commands with arguments use `multi-command` extension

Comment: I tried HTML related links, but it appear to work with keybindings, but not a task. For other reasons, I can't use keybindings for this it has to be task. I tried passing as array or as a object.  It returns:  Error: cannot open vscode-remote://dev-container%2B2f686f6d652f6167736d6974682f656e762f776f726b7370616365732f73616e646d616e2f6465762f646f636b6572/%24%7Bcommand%3AhtmlRelatedLinks.openFile%7D. Detail: Unable to read file 'vscode-remote://dev-container+2f686f6d652f6167736d6974682f656e762f776f726b7370616365732f73616e646d616e2f6465762f646f636b6572/${command:htmlRelatedLinks.openFile}'

Comment: I will see if I can make it work with remote file systems

Comment: I think you have confused tasks with keybindings. 
In tasks.json, "command" should be an external program, or a shell command (not vscode command). 
In keybindings.json, you can define a vscode command like this: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_binding-keyboard-shortcuts-to-tasks

Comment: I want to use tasks, not keybindings.  I have more tasks that I want to run that I have keybindings available. Also tasks are easy to remember and share with team members. Keybindings are not easy to share.